# How to make text animations

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am new in Front End and I was wondering if anyone can tell me how to make the text appears like in this website: https://colorlib.com/demo?theme=glint

From the bottom to the top?

Comment: Please try to provide a more specific context where and what tech stack you are planning to code the text animations. There are different frameworks and libraries to provide such functionality. I saw you want to use on WordPress but I'm not sure because you not saying it. I recommend you to be more specific and try some examples by yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You should get a look at the [W3.CSS Animations](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_animate.asp)

The exact effect you are looking for could be tryed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_animate-bottom) and is called a `slide-up effect`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="w3-container w3-center w3-animate-bottom">
  <h1>Animation is Fun!</h1>
  <p>The w3-animate-bottom class slides in an element from the bottom. 
</p>
```

Comment: Also add `opacity` to go from 0 to 1, for the slide in effect

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of jquery and css like in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/booTsTrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp) boostrap example, at the "Slide In Elements" section.